# Run javascript in winapi

Tags: javascript, winapi

I have a very simple js file:

```
function geoip_country_code() { return 'US'; }
function geoip_country_name() { return 'United States'; }
function geoip_city()         { return 'New York'; }
function geoip_region()       { return '06'; }
function geoip_region_name()  { return 'xxx'; }
function geoip_latitude()     { return '55'; }
function geoip_longitude()    { return '99'; }
function geoip_postal_code()  { return ''; }
function geoip_area_code()    { return ''; }
function geoip_metro_code()   { return ''; }
```

I would like to call `geoip_country_code` from a win32 code. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified a language but this is possible with COM; `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl`

```
sc->language="jscript";
sc->addcode("the js string");

result = sc->run("geoip_country_code", args);
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229669

Comment: Although it wasn't so easy to get to the documentation for `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl` I've managed to use a very similar method successfully - `sc->run("geoip_country_code",noArgs);` Thanks for pointing the right direction, you may as well change the answer to use `run` method so I can accept it. (if you won't I'll edit it and accept it anyway)

Answer (score 1):

If you won't be dealing with more complicated code than this I'd suggest that you use regex instead and just parse out the value you want returned. Else you need to supply information on what language you are writing this in. Win32 API does not support JS as far as I know (COM might be though) but there are several APIs out there in various languages that can run JS.

If you want to go for regex then this should do it:

```
function [a-zA-Z_]+\(\) { +return +'([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)'; +}
```